# mvc publish solution - not available on all projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, publishing

i have this MVC based solution, which i am trying to deploy, but the publish option is not available on the DataAccessModel1 project and the ideaworktelekriktests project. I am assuming this is because those are not web projects?

My MVC application cannot run without those projects, is there any workaround to this issue?

(I cannot post images due to reputation points)
Basically the three looks like this:

1. DataAccessModel1(data model)
2. Ideaworktelerik(web)
3. ideaworkteleriktests(test cases)

Let me know if you need more information guys. Thanks as always

Comment: The dependencies will be published too. How are the projects related?

Comment: If you post the hyper-link to the URL, someone can edit them in for you.

Comment: @CodeCaster the datamodel one providers connection to the database. website cannot work without it.

Comment: @JessicaPartridge i am not sure what you mean, is this related to the image?

Comment: If you have reference to DataAccessModel1 in Ideaworktelerik project than it will work when you publish your web app. Like @CodeCaster said the dependencies will be published too. You can check it in your bin folder, if you have DataAccessModel1 dll it will be published with your project